# pander on aov in knitr does not print?

Tags: knitr, pandoc, pander

I'm trying to print the outcome of an anova like so:

```
library(pander)
m.aov = aov(Sepal.Width ~ Species * Sepal.Length, iris)
pander(m.aov, split.table=Inf)
```

and I get this as expected if I type it into the console:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          &nbsp;            Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq   F value   Pr(>F)  
-------------------------- ---- -------- --------- --------- ---------
       **Species**          2    11.34     5.672     76.48   2.329e-23

     **Sepal.Length**       1    4.769     4.769     64.3    3.368e-13

 **Species:Sepal.Length**   2    1.513    0.7566     10.2    7.19e-05 

      **Residuals**        144   10.68    0.07417     NA        NA    
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Analysis of Variance Model
```

However, if I embed this into a `knitr` chunk, I don't get the table:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
library(pander)
m.aov = aov(Sepal.Width ~ Species * Sepal.Length, iris)
pander(m.aov, split.table=Inf)
```
````

Knit the above and one obtains

````
```r
pander(m.aov, split.table=Inf)
```
````

i.e., the code chunk with no output.

**Question**: Is this a bug (in knitr? pander?) or something I've overlooked? How can I work around it?

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.8      pander_0.5.1   vimcom_1.0-0   setwidth_1.0-3 colorout_1.0-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4   evaluate_0.5.5 formatR_1.0    Rcpp_0.11.2    stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: You have a typo: pass `m.aov` to `pander` instead of `aov`, and please try running the same with the most recent (dev) version of `pander`: https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/#installation

Comment: apologies; I did have `m.aov` in my script, just typo'd it copying it over. The behaviour is present with pander 0.5.1 (from CRAN), but is fixed in the github version 0.5.2, so I guess I will have to ensure that the people I distribute the report to have the github version, or I have also noticed that if I explicitly call `pander:::pander.aov(m.aov)` then it works, so in my function I could catch things that inherit from `aov` and handle them explicitly if the user does not have pander 0.5.2.

Comment: Voting to close as it's a bug in the current CRAN version pander package that is not present in the github version.

Comment: Thank you @mathematical.coffee, I'll release a minor update on CRAN in a few weeks.

Comment: @daroczig, in the current version, the command `pander:::pander.anova` has the same problem, it does not print if calling `pander` only

Comment: @Zhenglei the current version refers to the CRAN version or the dev (GitHub) version?

Comment: @daroczig，the dev version

Comment: @Zhenglei can you please post here or e.g. on pastebin/gist a reproducible example? It seems to work fine on my machine, but I might miss something. I tried `anova(aov(Sepal.Width ~ Species * Sepal.Length, iris))` based on the above examples.

Comment: @daroczig ```{r results='asis'}
require(car)
require(pander)
a <- Anova(aov(Sepal.Width ~ Species * Sepal.Length, iris))
for(i in 1:3) pander(a)
```

Comment: @daroczig basically it happened in loops or lapply. If calling `pander:::pander.anova`, the problem disappeared and print out the output as expected.

Comment: @Zhenglei ah, that's a special case -- as `pander` is not printing to `stdout` since `0.50` and there is no need to specify `results='asis'` (in most cases) for convenience, but if you want the old behaviour, then look for `knitr.auto.asis` [general option](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options) or in more details check [this blogpost on using `pander` inside of `knitr`](http://blog.rapporter.net/2014/09/pander-tables-inside-of-knitr.html).